# Counting number of vertical bars | in pandas string has strange behaviour?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of instances of vertical bars "|" in a each row of a particular column in a pandas dataframe. But using `str.count("|")` yields some strange behaviour:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['some text', None, 'a|few|vertical|bars', 'one|'])
df[0].str.count("|")
```

outputs

```
0    10.0
1     NaN
2    20.0
3     5.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

What's going on here? If I use `apply` instead, I get the expected answer:

```
df.apply(lambda x: str(x[0]).count("|"),axis=1)
```

yields

```
0    0
1    0
2    3
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, [pat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count) is a regex string and | is a regex operator, OR, so escape with '\', blackslash:

```
df[0].str.count('\|')
```

Output:

```
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    3.0
3    1.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

*Note:* `str.count` in the standard library is different from `pd.Series.str.count` where the former doesn't use regex, but the method from pandas does per docs linked above.

Comment: Damn, you beat me :p regex is the real reason!

Comment: Aha, thanks! That's what I needed to know.